# How do I make sure an aggregate exists before publishing an event?

Tags: node.js, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, wolkenkit

I was looking through the Wolkenkit API ... and it's not 100% clear how to know which commands require an aggregate ID and which ones do not.

From what I can tell, the client api offers something like this

```
app.accounting.invoice().issue({
  amount: 1000
});
```

which is fine for creating a new `invoice`, but it shouldn't be possible to run the following that intends to update something that exists

```
app.accounting.invoice().update({
  amount: 10
});
```

I assume this check should go into the command function, but how do I write it?

```
const commands = {
  update (invoice, command, mark) {
    const canInvoiceBeUpdated = // ...

    if (!canInvoiceBeUpdated) {
      return mark.asRejected('...');
    }

    // ... update invoice

    mark.asDone();
  }
};
```

What goes into `canInvoiceBeUpdated` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answered 2018-06-08 by [@goloroden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333873/golo-roden) in the [wolkenkit slack](http://slackin.wolkenkit.io/)*

I'll try to explain it to you: If you want a *new* aggregate, you omit the ID. So, e.g., to stick with the chat example, when you want to send a new message you do:

```
app.communication.message().send({ /* ... */ });
```

If, instead, you want to edit an *existing* message, e.g. to like it, then you have to provide the ID of the message:

```
const messageId = '...';

app.communication.message(messageId).like({ /* ... */ });
```

Within every command you will probably want to check that it only works on a new aggregate (which we call a *constructor command*) or only on an existing aggregate. The easiest way to check this is to use the aggregate's `exists` function, which returns `true` for new aggregates, and `false` otherwise. So, inside of a command, you could do something like this:

```
const commands = {
  send (message, command, mark) {
    if (!message.exists()) {
      return mark.asRejected('Aggregate does not exist yet.');
    }

    // ...

    mark.asDone();
  }
};
```

If you don't want to do this manually every time, you could also use a middleware for this, such as https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-command-tools … then the previous example comes down to:

```
const { only } = require('wolkenkit-command-tools');

// ...

const commands = {
  send: [
    only.ifExists(),
    (message, command, mark) {
      // ...

      mark.asDone();
    }
  ]
};
```

Please note that the current version of this middleware module is `3.0`, but that until wolkenkit `2.0` will be released, you will have to use version `2.0` of `wolkenkit-command-tools`.

Comment: PS: The `exists` function is now also part of the [wolkenkit documentation](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/latest/reference/creating-the-write-model/defining-commands/#verifying-whether-an-aggregate-exists).